# How to change order of integration?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{2a \cos \theta} f(r, \theta) \ dr \ d\theta$$

Hi everyone, Can you please help me in changing the order of integration in polar coordinates?

A general theory or method will be appreciated. I had searched a lot but unable to find the related theory.

Thanks

Comment: Usually one starts with plotting equations and looking at them.

Comment: This doesn't actually look like a case where changing the order is likely to serve any purpose.

Comment: $$ \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2a\cos(\theta)}f(r,\theta)\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta =\int_0^{2a}\int_0^{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2a}\right)}f(r,\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, in the question it's asked to change the order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different way to do it

The region is a semicircle centered at (a,0)

i.e.

$x^2 + y^2 = 2ax\\
x = r\cos \theta\\y=r\sin\theta\\
r^2 = 2ar\cos \theta\\
r = 2a\cos\theta$

$u = r-a\\
\phi = 2\theta$

$\int_0^a\int_0^\pi f(u+a, \frac {\phi}{2}) (2\ d\phi \ du)$

Not exactly what you were asked for.

Comment: I don't see no circle.

Comment: plot $r =  2a \cos \theta$  You will get a circle.

Comment: Erm, so you assert that $(\theta,\cos\theta)$ desribes a circle when $\theta\in [0,\pi/2]$?

Comment: I have added some detail for you,

Comment: I still don't see any circle.

Comment: Then how would you represent a circle of radius a, centered a units from the origin in polar coordinates?

Comment: Now, I see what you are saying. It's in polar coordinates only. Ok, then fine. I see the circle now. :-)